# How can I get only the field from a vuetify table to post in axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

How can I get only the field from a vuetify table to post by in axios, I have a table as I show in the following code

```
 <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              append-icon="mdi-magnify"
              label="Search"
              single-line
              hide-details
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="students"
            :search="search"
          >
            <template  v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
              <v-btn v-if="item.status" @click="add(item)">Add</v-btn>
              
              <v-btn v-else disabled>Temporarily no access</v-btn>   
            </template>
            
          </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </div>
```

and from script I have the following code

```
 const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   vuetify: new Vuetify(),    
   data() {
         return {
           search: '',
           headers: [
             { text: 'Number list', align: 'start', value: 'id'},
             { text: 'Name', align: 'start', value: 'name'},
             { text: 'Options', value: 'status' }
           ],
           students: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: pedro,
          status: activo,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: juan,
          status: activo,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: jose,
          status: activo,
        },
       ]
         };
       },
    methods: {
        add (item) {
        axios.post('http://localhost/list?id=' + item.id)
          .then(response => {
            this.response = response
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
      },
    
    }
 });
```

What I want to do is that when it is clicked I only sent the id per post with axios but when I click it I get an error in the console that says that item is undefined that is my main error, and as you can see I need it to be first verify that the student's status is active. Below I also add an image of the generated table for further reference.

[table reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhR27.png)

***Edit***

i forgot put

```
 @click="add(item)"
```

but still doesn´t work, no longer even an error appears in the console even if it has the catch

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 <v-btn v-if="item.estado" @click="add(item)">Add</v-btn>
```

Try 2:
Check first if `item` is coming through correctly by adding the following line. Maybe this will help in tracking down the problem

```
     <template v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
              <p>Debug item text: {{item}}</p>
              <v-btn v-if="item.status" @click="add(item)">Add</v-btn>
              
              <v-btn v-else disabled>Temporarily no access</v-btn>   
            </template>
```

Comment: it is true forget to put that, but that is not the problem, it still does not work

Comment: Added additional attempt at solving this